# Unable to get data in an object in .drl file

Tags: drools

I have two rules in my .drl file

```
rule "Monitor"  
when
    s : Test1( type == Test1.X )    
    n : Test123()
then
    n.monitor();        
    drools.setFocus("Rules");
end

rule "Utilization"
agenda-group "Rules"
when
    s : Test1( type == Test1.X , newValue > oldValue )
    n : Test123()
then
    //Do something
end
```

monitor() is a method in the class Test123, and this method sets values to some variables in the class Test1, by using Getters and Setters. And this method returns an object 'object'.   In my second rule I want to compare values (newValue > oldValue) in the object 'object'. How can I perform this operation.

Comment: Sooooo..... there are some issues here that you are not explaining... Could you add your "Test1" and "Test123" classes or at least the pertinent parts like "newValue" and "oldValue" so we know what you are talking about and maybe a snippet of the implementation of how these rules are being run?  To me it seems like you are having some init issues or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the old value in global variable and compare with it in second rule.